# Python's re.findall seems to work when not in function, but fails when in a function

Tags: python, regex, nlp, python-re

I'm currently working on a function for finding the occurrences of keywords in a text, using regex to find the keywords that occur in a given text and to find the context (100 chars around the matched keyword). Below is the function and a text example:

```
import re

def scan_for_kws(txt, keywords = ["solar"]):
    matching_kws = []
    matching_sentences = []
    #For loop to append the full element of any strings identified from the keywords list
    for kws in keywords:
        if re.compile(kws).search(txt):
            matching_kws.append(kws)
            surrounding_pattern = ".{0, 100}" + kws + ".{0, 100}"
            matching_sentence = re.findall(re.compile(surrounding_pattern), txt)
            matching_sentences.append(matching_sentence)
    return matching_kws, matching_sentences
```

When running this on the text example:

```
text_ex = "the solar panel sits on the lake"
```

it returns:

```
(['solar'], [[]])
```

i.e., matching_sentences is empty. On the other hand if I run the for-loop out of the function:

```
keywords = ["solar"]
matching_kws = []
matching_sentences = []
for kws in keywords:
   if re.compile(kws).search(text_ex):
       matching_kws.append(kws)
       surrounding_pattern = ".{0,100}" + kws + ".{0,100}"
       matching_sentence = re.findall(re.compile(surrounding_pattern), text_ex)
       matching_sentences.append(matching_sentence)
```

the outputs are:

```
['solar'], [['the solar panel sits on the lake']]
```

I've tried other arrangements of the code that are different (e.g., searching in the if statement with the surrounding_pattern variable) and they also fail. I know this not the most efficient code (doing the search once then doing it again), but that is not issue for the length of the text documents I'm working with. I can't see why this error should be coming up, given that the loops are identical except for one being contained in a function and one not. Full example here:

```
import re

text_ex = "the solar panel sits on the lake"

def scan_for_kws(txt, keywords = ["solar"]):
    matching_kws = []
    matching_sentences = []
    for kws in keywords:
        if re.compile(kws).search(txt):
            matching_kws.append(kws)
            surrounding_pattern = ".{0, 100}" + kws + ".{0, 100}"
            matching_sentence = re.findall(re.compile(surrounding_pattern), txt)
            matching_sentences.append(matching_sentence)
    return matching_kws, matching_sentences

keywords = ["solar"]
matching_kws = []
matching_sentences = []
for kws in keywords:
   if re.compile(kws).search(text_ex):
       matching_kws.append(kws)
       surrounding_pattern = ".{0,100}" + kws + ".{0,100}"
       matching_sentence = re.findall(re.compile(surrounding_pattern), text_ex)
       matching_sentences.append(matching_sentence)
       
matching_kws2, matching_sentences2 = scan_for_kws(text_ex, keywords = ["solar"])
```

Comment: You must have `surrounding_pattern = ".{0,100}" + kws + ".{0,100}"`, not `surrounding_pattern = ".{0, 100}" + kws + ".{0, 100}"`

Comment: Thank you very much! I wasn't aware that regex syntax was that strict and that difference completely slipped past me.